# How to wrap method invokation inside bundle?

Tags: java, logging, osgi, bundle, aop

I have cq5 application.

we have a following class hierarchy (pseudocode):

```
class serviceA{
   methodA1(){...}
   methodA2(){...}
   methodA3(){
      ...
      httprequest
      ...
   }
   methodA4(){...}
}

class serviceB{
   methodB1(){
      ...
      httprequest
      ...
      httprequest
      ...
      httprequest
   }
   methodB2(){...}
   methodB3(){...}
   methodB4(){
     ...
     httprequest
     ...
   }
}

class serviceC{
   methodC1(){
       ...
       httprequest
       ...
       httprequest
       ...
   }
   methodC2(){...}
   methodC3(){    
    ...
    httprequest
    ....
    }
   methodC4(){...}
}
```

And I need to Log before and after httprequest (to measure the time).

But it is very sad to change code inside every service.

Can you provide more graceful decision?

Will `OSGI` work with `Aspectj`?

What about `@AspectService` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly follow the [SOC principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) you have to create a separate class for the HTTP request:

```
public class HTTPRequest {
    public void doRequest() { ... } // change signature according to your needs
}
```

An instance of this class now must be used in your service methods.

With that design, it is very easy to place logging behavior. Simply change the `doRequest` method.

Comment: At this case I should use "oldHTTPRequest" class inside HTTPRequest

Comment: and rewrite all methods

Comment: my colleagues say that I cannot use AspectJ but I don't understand why

Comment: Maybe your colleagues are just afraid of new or unknown technologies and use "won't work" as a killer phrase. Why should you not be able to use AspectJ? It does not need more than Java SE plus a runtime library for compile-time weaving or a weaving agent for load-time weaving. In combination with OSGi you can take a look at [Equinox Weaving](http://eclipse.org/equinox/weaving/) for further information.